# Keep selected item from dropdown list - PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to build some dropdown lists that retain their selections after submitting the form. Similar questions that treat this issue did not help, since I am populating the list from an array inside a php tag.

I will post the code for the implementation of a list below.

```
<select id="select_city" name="select_city">
      <?php

     . . . *building the array from data in xml* . . .

      foreach($tmp as $el)
      {
        echo "<option value='$el'>$el</option>";
      }
      ?>
</select>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're posting back your form to the same script, you can decide the whether to add the `selected` attribute to any given option simply by comparing its value with the value posted back:

```
<select id="select_city" name="select_city">
      <?php

     . . . *building the array from data in xml* . . .

      foreach($tmp as $el)
      {
        echo "<option value='$el' ".($el == ($_POST["select_city"] ?? "")  ? "selected" : "").">$el</option>";
      }
      ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Been struggling with this for the past 2 days.